# get the select element in .NET using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have ajax function like this to run on HTML select list

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlemp,
                success: function (returndata) {
                    if (returndata.ok) {
                        //  var data = eval("" + returndata.data + "");
                        select.empty();
                        select.append($('<option>' + "" + '</option>'));
                        $.each(returndata.data, function (rec) {

                            select.append($('<option>' + returndata.data[rec].Name + '</option>'));
                        });
                        select.show('slow');
                        select.change();
                    }
                    else {
                        window.alert(' error : ' + returndata.message);
                    }

                }
            }
    );
```

and this is the HTML element

```
        <select id="cmbDept"></select>
```

How can i get the value of the selected item in the controller using MVC 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Us `FormCollection` as parameter in your controller. And assign `name` to the `select`

```
<select id="cmbDept" name="cmbDept"></select>
```

Now the `FormCollection` has this posted value.

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        string val = "";
        foreach (var key in form.AllKeys)
        {
            if (key.Contains("cmbDept"))
            {
                 val = form.Get(key);
            }
        }
        --your code here with the posted values
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have 4 ways to do that
1. the you can bind ti the change event of the select `$(select).change(function(){})` and send an `ajax` request again wrapping the selected value which you will be able to get in the `controller`
2. you can keep a `hidden input` in your view binded to a property in the view's model now bind to the change of the select and fill the input with the value this way whenever your form is posted back it will have the values properly binded to the `model`
3. @Don saved me from writing the third way so read his ans. 
4. if you have a `model` that this view is binded to then simple keep a `property` in the `model` with the name `cmbDept` and selected value would be automatically posted back

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the `select` element on the client, just use `$("#cmbDept").val()`.

To get the value of the element once it's submitted to the server, add a `name="cmbDept"` to your `select` and simply create a parameter named `cmbDept` in the controller action your `$.ajax` call is is posting to.